# Python Zfill not working

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, range

What I'm trying to do is print all possible combinations for a 10 digit combination...  However for 1 I want it to print 0000000001, 0000000002, etc.  However ZFill is not working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
a = range(0, 1000000)
print str(a).zfill(1000000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print str(a).zfill(7)

                  ^^
```

Specify width here.You can simply do

```
print map(lambda x:str(x).zfill(7), range(0, 10))
```

Answer (score 7):

You are doing `zfill` on `list` object. Instead, you need to perform `zfill` on each item of list. Below is the sample example for range 10:

```
>>> a = range(0, 10)

#                 v  this value represent the count of zeros
#                 v  It should be `7` in your case
>>> [str(i).zfill(10) for i in a]
['0000000000', '0000000001', '0000000002', '0000000003', '0000000004', '0000000005', '0000000006', '0000000007', '0000000008', '0000000009']
```

---

As per the [`str.zfill()` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill):

> **string.zfill(s, width)**
>
> Pad a numeric string **s** on the left with zero digits until the given **width** is reached. Strings starting with a sign are handled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

you can also let [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) handle the filling:

```
for a in range(1000000):
    print('{:07d}'.format(a))
```